# Excel Macro find text and store result in new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really new in VBA so my expertise is minimal, however. I have three columns A, B, C

My Goal:
is to loop through the Entire Colum C and look for Specific String. 
if it's equal then I want to take a respective row including(columns A, B)and store it inside (Sheet2) row by row:

Here is what I'm experimenting please help.

```
 Sub FindString()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim DataCount As Integer
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        DataCount = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In Range("C1:C" & DataCount)
            If InStr(cell.Value, "cmt") > 0 Then
                  MsgBox "The String is Found"
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information missing but this will get you close. Since you already know when the string is found, it will copy the entire row and paste it into Sheet2. `i` is added to help iterate through the rows that are found so they're not pasted on top of each other but that can be changed.

```
Sub FindString()
Dim cell As Range
Dim DataCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

i = 1
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    'Changed to column C instead
    DataCount = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cell In Range("C1:C" & DataCount)
        If InStr(cell.Value, "cmt") > 0 Then
              MsgBox "The String is Found"
              Rows(cell.Row).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1)
              i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: this did almost the trick it found the first equal and exit the loop, how can I make it go through all column C.

Comment: Right now the DataCount variable is counting the rows in column L, change that to C and it should do it

Comment: Can I select specific column eg Only [A && B] if the string is found and past it into  sheet2

Comment: Yes, you could instead use 'Range(Cells(cell.Row, 1), Cells(cell.Row, 2)).Copy' and it should only copy A:B from that row

Comment: I noticed that you used Range, what if I want to choose specific column like A and D form that row only for example.

Comment: I haven't tried it in this context but I believe you could use 'Union(' instead

Comment: You Are absolutely correct, you have been so supportive I Thank you.